# jQuery stop custom slide when no more items

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am creating a custom slider to user to view the work process
[image: Picture 1]

When user clicks the button, the slider will scroll to left or right based on the button user click. But after user clicks multiple times, slider might scroll too much and left a big space like the picture below
[image: Picture 2]

Is there any ways I can make the slider stop if no more items behind like picture 3?

[image: Picture 3]

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
   var direction = 1;
   
   const slideSec = document.querySelector('.movingsec .container');
   
   const slideItem = document.querySelectorAll('.movingsec .image-box');
   
   var maxItem = slideItem.length;
   
   $('.btnPrev').click(function(){
       direction = 0;
       runSlide(direction);
   });
   
   $('.btnNext').click(function(){
      direction = 1;
      runSlide(direction);
   });
   
   var current = 0;
   
   function runSlide(direction){
       if(direction === 1){
           current = current + 1;
           if(current === maxItem){
               current = maxItem - 1;
           }
       }
       
       if(direction === 0){
           current = current - 1;
           if(current < 0){
               current = 0;
           }
       }
       
       var destination = current * 215;
       $(slideSec).css('transform','translateX(-'+destination+'px)');
   }
});
```

The code above is I created for this slider.

Comment: you didn't include any html so it's up to the speculation that can be made over the js. You are moving the whole container instead of actually sliding anything inside it. It's not clear how it should behave relative to its parent since when you move the container, according to the information given, you are doing it relative to the whole viewport. How many items are supposed to be shown in the visible part of this slider? can you just include a working demo with the simplified html?

Comment: Yes, that would very helpful if you provide any html.

Comment: @DiegoD given your analysis, then I would *guess* that .container was inside another "container" with `overflow:hidden` - the CSS would also help.  See [mcve].

Comment: If this is supposed to work for a _dynamic_ slider width, then you will need to _calculate_ the point from which on you must not move the whole thing any more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work (depending on your html and css):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    const amend = true;

    const slideSec = document.querySelector('.movingsec .container');
    const slideItem = document.querySelectorAll('.movingsec .image-box');
    const slideContainer = $(slideSec).parent();
      
    const maxItem = slideItem.length;
    const slideWidth = $(slideItem[0]).outerWidth(true);

    $('.btnPrev').click(function() {
        runSlide(0);
    });
    $('.btnNext').click(function() {
        runSlide(1);
    });

    var current = 0;

    function runSlide(direction) {
        var amendLast = 0;
        if (direction === 1) {
            const containerWidth = slideContainer.width();
            const canShowSlides = parseInt(containerWidth / slideWidth);
            const hiddenSlides = maxItem - canShowSlides - current;
            if (hiddenSlides <= 0) {
                return;
            }
            amendLast = amend && hiddenSlides == 1 ? containerWidth % slideWidth : 0;
            current = current + 1;
        }
        if (direction === 0) {
            if (current === 0) {
                return;
            }
            current = current - 1;
        }
        const destination = current * slideWidth - amendLast;
        $(slideSec).css('transform', 'translateX(-' + destination + 'px)');
    }
});
```

It should handle dynamic container width and static slide width with margins.

Change *amend* to `false` if you want an extra space after the last slide.